# как обрабатывать через кастомный onTouchListener не теряя onClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener, onclicklistener

мне нужно реагировать на свайп влево, для этого я использую этот класс в качестве onTouchListener:

```
open class OnSwipeTouchListener(ctx: Context?) : OnTouchListener {
private val gestureDetector: GestureDetector
override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    //обработка клика
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
}

private inner class GestureListener : SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    private val SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100
    private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100

    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun onFling(
        e1: MotionEvent,
        e2: MotionEvent,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        var result = false
        try {
            val diffY = e2.y - e1.y
            val diffX = e2.x - e1.x
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(
                        velocityX
                    ) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD
                ) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight()
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft()
                    }
                }
                result = true
            } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(
                    velocityY
                ) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD
            ) {
                if (diffY > 0) {
                    onSwipeBottom()
                } else {
                    onSwipeTop()
                }
            }
            result = true
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
        return result
    }
}

fun onSwipeRight() {}
open fun onSwipeLeft() {}
fun onSwipeTop() {}
fun onSwipeBottom() {}

init {
    gestureDetector = GestureDetector(ctx, GestureListener())
}
```

}

это работает, но click listener, который я устанавливаю стандартным способом из-за этого не работает.
я понимаю почему так происходит, но не знаю как это исправить

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вы упустили вызов метода super внутри обработки, что бы пробросить вызов on click дальше.